# Return Backgroundworker without RunWorkerCompleted

Tags: c#, wpf, backgroundworker

Im writing on an Installation for my Application. So Im using Steps.

So I have Methods like `Step01()` and `Step02` which changes the UI.
Between `Step01` and `Step02` I need to use a Backgroundworker (login).

So I created another method `private bool CheckLogin()` which is calling like this:

ButtonClick Event:

```
if(CheckLogin())
{
    Step02();
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(ErrorMessage)
}
```

Because `CheckLogin()` is a `boolean` I need to return `true` or `false`. But in this method I need to use the `Backgroundworker` (for Loading Animation).

My `CheckLogin()` Method:

```
private bool CheckLogin(string username, string password)
{
    if(globalLoginWorker.IsBusy)
    {
        globalLoginWorker.CancelAsync();
        LoadingButtonCircular.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        List<string> arguments = new List<string>();
        arguments.Add(username);
        arguments.Add(password);
        LoadingButtonCircular.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        BackButton.IsEnabled = false;
        globalLoginWorker.RunWorkerAsync(arguments);
    }
}
```

In this Backgroundworker (`globalLoginWorker`) I have some Error Handlings (Wrong Password, Not existing User, etc.)
And now I need to return a true or false from the Backgroundworker so that I can return a true or false in the `CheckLogin()` method.

Something like:

```
if(globalLoginWorker.RunWorkerAsync(arguments)
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

Because I can't wait for a Backgroundworker until it's finished.

Edit:
Im now trying to use a async Task instead of a Backgroundworker. But with this method the application will freeze.

```
private async Task<bool> CheckLogin(string username, string password)
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000) //(to test Loading animation / freeze)
    return true;
}
```

Button Click Event:

```
LoadingButtonCircular.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
if(CheckLogin("test", "test").Result)
    MessageBox.Show("true");
else
    MessageBox.Show("false");
LoadingButtonCircular.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Comment: don't use backgroundworker for WPF. use async/await

Comment: @mm8 In the DoWork I check if the User exists in Database and if the password etc. is correct. I used a BackgroundWorker to show an Loading Animation while processing. Without a Backgroundworker the application will freeze while processing.

Comment: Move the code from the DoWork event handler to a Task and await the task.

Comment: @mm8 I edited my Question to show u my problem with the Task method.

Comment: @KushGene: You need to run Thread.Sleep on a background thread. Please refer to my answer.

Comment: Task is not guranteed to run on new thread, so Thread.Sleep can freeze your UI. Use `await Task.Delay(5000);` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `BackgroundWorker` doesn't return any value. It executes an operation on a separate thread and raises the `RunWorkerCompleted` event when the background operation has completed.

What you could do here is to move the code that you have in your `DoWork` event handler to a `Task` and `await` this one, e.g.:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (await CheckLogin())
    {
        Step02();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ErrorMessage)
    }
}

private async Task<bool> CheckLogin()
{
    return await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //this code runs on a background thread...
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        return true;
    });
}
```

Please refer to MSDN for more information about the async and await keywords that were introduced in C# 5 to greatly simplifying writing asynchronous code: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/. You don't need to use `BackgroundWorker` any longer.

Comment: Great. Thanks. So `BackgroundWorker` is outdated and all are using asynchronous code now? I will read more about that. Thanks for that information.